# Javascript image manipulation library that does not depend on Canvas

Tags: javascript, image-processing, web-worker

Is there any image manipulation library in Javascript that does not depend on canvas so it can be used in a webworker?

I'm looking for operations over raster images such as scaling, rotating and cropping.

Comment: Where do you get raster and in what form?

Comment: I can get the image out of a canvas in form of imageData and the convert that to an RGB array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jimp. written for node, ported to browser. https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp/tree/master/packages/jimp/browser

Answer (score 1):

If i'm not wrong Raphaël.js uses canvas too.

Sorry but **there is no such library** working independent of browser's canvas. Javascript itself can not manipulate images.

If you need to manipulate images in the client you will have to use js+canvas or flash(it has his own draw api). If not possible ... move your manipulation logic to the server.

Comment: In the end an image is just an array of rgb values. Why can't there be a library that manipulates images in array form?

Answer (score 0):

Try Raphaël  http://raphaeljs.com/

It works with both SVG and VML so it supports a broad range of browsers.

Comment: I'm looking for raster images instead of vector images. I'm looking for things like scaling, rotating, cropping... I'll update the question. Thanks a lot anyway.